# NHibernate - Creating a proxy instance failed (on IIS8 but ok with dev server)

Tags: c#, iis, nhibernate, .net-2.0

I have to work on already developed solution which is using NHibernate (v1.2.1.4000) with SQL Server 2008.

The application is using .NET Framework 2.0 due to Membership authentication and other stuffs.

This is working in Visual Studio - I can debug it, run in. But failed when deployed in IIS (v8.0)

Exception is:

> Duplicate type name within an assembly.
>   HibernateException: Creating a proxy instance failed.

And it occurred whenever database is fetched to get some models.

I have googled on this issue and have some suggestion to use nhiberante (v3.3.x).

But the lots of interfaces and method parameters are different in v3. so it is breaking implementaion of the source code.

Several questions regarding this exist on stackoverflow but no luck yet

Comment: When debugging with VS, is it with old Cassini dev server or with IIS Express? Switch to IIS Express for debugging if it is not already done.

Comment: @ Frédéric, Thanks. It is using IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a concurrency trouble, something like singleton initialization failing to ensure uniqueness of its initialization, occurring only under load.

Especially check your session factory. Put logs when building it, check it is not built multiple times. Try triggering your singleton initializations from Application_Start if they are not already triggered from there.

Avoid singleton lazy initializations unless they are really heavy and not needed for most of you application HTTP requests. In such case, make sure their logic is thread safe and avoid running concurrent initializations (something like [`LazyThreadSafetyMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `ExecutionAndPublication` instead of `PublicationOnly`: it requires stricter locking but must be done that way for building the `ISessionFactory`, if it is done through lazy initialization.)

Comment: It is a bug in NHibernate https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3172 and it is suggested to use NHibernate 3 or more.
I have upgraded the solution to CLR v4 and using NHibernate 4 too. But now castle (v3.0.0) is not working because castle.facilities does not have support for v3.

Comment: Castle was the usual proxy generator configured for NHibernate prior to its version 3. NHibernate v3 and higher embed their own proxy generator and does not need an external one anymore.